# Calling precompiled contracts from a pure function

Tags: solidity, precompiled-contracts

I'm trying to call some of the new precompiled contract (`ecmul`) from a `pure` function but it fails with:

```
browser/ballot.sol:11:23: TypeError: Function declared as pure, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state and thus requires non-payable (the default) or payable.
            if iszero(call(not(0), 0x07, 0, input, 0x60, p, 0x40)) {
                      ^--^
```

This is the sample contract (requires solc 0.4.19):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Ballot {
    function ecmul(uint256 x, uint256 y, uint256 scalar) public pure returns (uint256[2] p) {
        // With a public key (x, y), this computes p = scalar * (x, y).
        uint256[3] memory input;
        input[0] = x;
        input[1] = y;
        input[2] = scalar;
        assembly {
            // call ecmul precompile
            if iszero(call(not(0), 0x07, 0, input, 0x60, p, 0x40)) {
                revert(0, 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Taken from the article [precompiles & solidity](https://medium.com/@bekahoxoo/precompiles-solidity-e5d29bd428c4).

If I declare the function as `view` it will work but seems as unnecessary since it is a precompiled contract it should not modify the storage of any contract.

Comment: You say using `view` seems unnecessary, are there any other specific reasons you want to use `pure` instead of `view`?

Comment: @willjgriff My main issue is that modifying it to `view` forces me to modify all functions that use `ecmul` to be declared as `view`, and this forces any function that calls one of those to also be declared as `view`.

Comment: Linking the OP's Reddit post as well:
https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/7p8b86/it_is_possible_to_call_a_precompiled_contracts/

Answer (score 3):

Firstly note that the `view` modifier, as seen in the doc [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#view-functions) doesn't allow modifying of the state, it only allows reading of the state and behaves the same as `constant` (the modifier used for these code snippets in the article you've linked to). The `pure` modifier, in the doc [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#pure-functions) prevents both modifying and reading of the state.

To answer your question, it seems like using `call()` with any arguments raises this error when the `pure` modifier, which prevents reading of the state, is used. Which makes sense as `call()` needs to read the state to get the contract code at the address specified so it can execute a function on it.

Comment: The thing is precompiled contracts do not read and do not modify their state. One can argue that they do not have state. As an example `sha256()` is a precompiled contract and you can call it from a `pure` function.

Comment: If they're not in the state and the EVM doesn't have to read from the state to get them then I guess the compiler just doesn't know what the precompiled code addresses are. For all other contract addresses `view` is required and it doesn't consider these addresses different.

Comment: Perhaps functions will be added to Solidity to represent these precompiles in future like the `sha256()` and `ecrecvoer()` functions.

Comment: Yes, I hope eventually all precompiled contracts will be added to solidity. I was hopping for a workaround.